# Error in executing SAS code with pass-through

Tags: sas

I'm trying to run the code below, but it is returning with an error, I already checked the syntax and it doesn't seem to be wrong, but the error persists

```
proc sql;
       connect to oracle as BD (user = &varUserDBRtdbm. 
                                password = &varPassDBRtdbm.
                                path = &varPathRtdbmProd.);
               select *
                           from connection to BD
                               (select * 
                                   from (select *
                                           from rtdbm.base_atendimento
                                               where trim(dat_abertura) not in ('NA', 'A')
                                                   and UPPER(trim(cod_caso)) not in ('123','N/A','NA','DIGITAL', '001','NULL','DIGITAL','TESTE','LUCAS')
                                                   and trunc(to_date(dat_abertura,'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS'))       >= to_date('01/08/2020','DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS')
                                                   ) a,
                                                   rtdbm.base_oferta b
                                                       where a.cod_caso = b.cod_caso) BY BD;
       disconnect from BD;
   quit;
```

part of the error presented:

```
                                                      ) a,
66                                                      rtdbm.nba_tra_oferta b
67                                                          where a.cod_caso = b.cod_caso) BY BD;
                                                          __
                                                          22
                                                          76
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ',', GROUP, HAVING, ORDER, WHERE.  

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

Comment: Does the oracle query work it you run it with some other tool? Like sqlplus or Toad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `BY BD`

Your code is structured

```
select * from connection to BD 
(
  ...
)
by BD;
```

`by <connection>` is for `Proc SQL` `EXECUTE` statement and not needed here.

Comment: Thanks Richard, removing the "BY BD" the code ran, but I had to create a table, because only the select was generating a very large base to view, thank you very much !!!

Comment: Super! In my experience, rarely use just `SELECT` and standard ODS output to examine a result set; almost always `create table` and viewtable.